# jq filter to include unfound select

Tags: json, csv, jq

I am trying to filter through tags of this [JSON output](http://pastebin.com/RjjBH7g4)

Selecting through the Tags[] and display the selected values if the key exist.

My jq filter looks like this :

```
jq -r ".Reservations[]
 | [.OwnerId,
    .Instances[].InstanceId,
    .Instances[].Placement.AvailabilityZone,
    (.Instances[].Tags[]?|select(.Key==OtherTag)|.Value),
    (.Instances[].Tags[]?|select(.Key==Name)|.Value) ]
 | @csv"
```

The output looks like this

```
"xxxxxxxxxx9,i-d414ce0b,ap-southeast-2b,webserver2"
```

I would like it to include the unfounded select tags and fill it in as empty field in the csv 
like below :

```
"xxxxxxxxxx9,i-d414ce0b,ap-southeast-2b,,webserver2"
```

What should I do in jq to achieve that? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: So I've made a bit of progress here. by using map and select. 
'.Reservations[] | [.OwnerId, .Instances[].InstanceId, .Instances[].Placement.AvailabilityZone, (.Instances[].Tags | map( if (select(.Key=="Name")) then .Value else "" end)   ), (.Instances[].Tags | map( if (select(.Key=="OtherTag")) then .Value else "" end)   )  ]'  But I now end up with empty array in the result []. is there anyway to convert empty array to a null value ? basically squash all the values of that array into a string? hope this makes sense

Comment: Please include all the relevant information in the question directly and not linked from other sites. Links become outdated or websites go down.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `select/1`, use `filter/1`, where:

```
def filter(f): if f then . else "" end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **from_entries** to handle the `.Tags`

```
  .Reservations[]
| .OwnerId as $owner
| .Instances[]
| .InstanceId as $id    
| .Placement.AvailabilityZone as $az
| .Tags
| from_entries
| "\($owner),\($id),\($az),\(.OtherTag//""),\(.Name//"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [alternative operator `//`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Alternativeoperator://):

```
jq -r '.Reservations[]
 | [.OwnerId,
    .Instances[].InstanceId,
    .Instances[].Placement.AvailabilityZone,
    (.Instances[].Tags[]?|select(.Key=="OtherTag")|.Value)//"",
    (.Instances[].Tags[]?|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value)//"" ]
| @csv'
```

Output:

```
"683100487279","i-d414ce0b","ap-southeast-2b","","webserver2"
```